# How to add a Gradient point with CSS in the background?

Tags: html, css, colors, gradient, effects

Is it possible using **just HTML and CSS** to create a **gradient dot** in the **background**?

This should be quite easy to do with the IMG, but is there also a pure CSS variant?

[Example](https://antara.studio/)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use something like this:

```
background: rgb(3,164,153);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(3,164,153,1) 0%, rgba(3,164,153,0.3660057773109243) 35%, rgba(3,164,153,0) 100%);
```

`radial-gradient` is used to create circular or elliptical gradients. I am keeping the color constant (`rgba(3,164,153,1)`) while increasing the transparency.

You can read more about radial-gradient here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient

Also, I used this tool to create the gradient: https://cssgradient.io/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `radial-gradient` property.

```
background: radial-gradient(#cfb37a, transparent);
```